# XAML Design data isn't working for RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I've setup my root UI element to bind to design-time data for the DataContext, as shown below:

```
<Grid
    ...
    d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:MainPageSampleData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"
    ...
>
```

This lets Visual Studio update the Design view with design-time data, so that I don't have to keep running the app to see how it'll really look.

For example, if I declare this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalBalance}"/>
```

,the `TextBlock` nicely uses my design data

However, as soon as I switch to a `RichTextBlock`, it doesn't seem to work. Note that when I actually run the App, everything seems fine, so this is just a problem with the Design view. Here's what the `RichTextBlock` code looks like:

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="{Binding TotalBalance}"/>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

The above code just shows an empty `RichTextBlock` in the xaml Design view, but everything looks good when I run the app.

How can I get the design data to work with `RichTextBlock`?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview (Version 12.0.20623.01)

Comment: Have you ever experienced this problem in expression blend too ?

Comment: I have not used blend.